# asp.net Windows Forms Authentication for Admin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, admin

Im using C# and ASP.NET.
I have this file structure on my website:

```
~\Admin\SecuredFolder\ManageWebsite.aspx
~\Admin\Login.aspx
~\Homepage.aspx
```

What i'm trying to achieve is pretty much simple but i guess all my attempts till now turned out too complex and i'm kinda confused.

my goals:

- **Homepage.aspx** and **Login.aspx** should be public for all (anonymous users)
- **SecuredFolder** should be for logged users ONLY (ie: admin users). Whoever attempt to access any page in this folder (without being logged) should be redirected to login page.
- Once login succeeds it will successfully redirect to **ManageWebsite.aspx**

I know this supposed to be a simple implementation but i feel like I have not internalized it properly yet.

Hope any of you could provide me an example.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this webconfig in securedfolder `~\Admin\SecuredFolder\`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="admin" />
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

put this in webconfig of root folder `~\`

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  <location>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>

        <allow users="*"/>

      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Right now my problem is that after i tried to login, the secured page still throws me back to the login page again. Assuming im using a certain role i'd like to allow access to (like Srinivas's answer above), how should my Login.aspx behave exactly?  and also, what if i got many pages and folders on my root i'd like to allow access (besides homepage.aspx) ? should i only write path="/" ? would  that be a mistake?

Comment: Thanks, the problem left is that the login page isn't working correctly. I basiclly got two text boxes and a button which try to redirect, i'm not sure how to take care of the role issue.

Comment: @Popokoko : what do you mean by "i'm not sure how to take care of the role issue"?

Comment: right now my login page is not quite smart, doing redirect to the secured page doesn't guarantee it's an Admin user. i'm guessing this is a pretty newbish question but ill ask anyway - how should i handle that?

Answer (score 0):

To your root web.config add these to make Homepage and Login aspx pages public

```
  <location path="Homepage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Inside the Secure folder add a web.config file and to that add these to allow all contents inside `SecuredFolder` to be accessible only to `Admin` roles

```
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
```

After successful authentication, in Login.aspx, check the users role, if the role is that of `Admin`, redirect him to the `ManageWebsite.aspx page`

Comment: 1. what about if i have many more pages like homepage.aspx and i dont wanna put all of them as a location path in the web.config? can't i somehow allow all of them to be 'public' ? 2. i'm not sure about the last part of "check the users role", how should i implement that? right now I have 2 texts boxes and a login button on my login.aspx page. 3. should i configure something related to windows forms in the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

**Place a web.config in your SecuredFolder** and add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow roles="admin" />
          <deny users ="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now it will only allow the logged in(admin) user to access its contents.

You can also add `<authentication>` to your **root web.config** to automatically redirect an unauthorized user to the login page.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~\Admin\Login.aspx" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="AutoDetect" protection="All" requireSSL="false" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" defaultUrl="Homepage.aspx" path="/"/>
</authentication>
```